# Function IIF in loop statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code that loops through the rows of an array then store the values into another array. No problem at the code in fact but I am trying to improve my skills and learn new skills
This is the code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    a = Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2))
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
                n = n + 1
                If a(i, j) <> Empty Then b(n) = a(i, j)
            Next j
        Else
            For j = UBound(a, 2) To LBound(a, 2) Step -1
                n = n + 1
                If a(i, j) <> Empty Then b(n) = a(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Range("M2").Resize(n).Value = Application.Transpose(b)
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is to compact the nested loop and this is my try

```
For j = iif(i mod2=1,LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2),UBound(a, 2) To LBound(a, 2) Step -1)
```

But this seems not to ne valid. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't nest `Step -1` inside an `IIf` like that.

Comment: `For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2) Step  iif(i mod2=1,1,-1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - no because OP wants to flip the `UBound` and `LBound` in the 2nd option.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks a lot. In my code, there are two cases .. I tried `For j = IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, LBound(a, 2), UBound(a, 2)) To IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, UBound(a, 2), LBound(a, 2)) & IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, Empty, Step - 1)` This doesn't work too but may clarify the issue well

Comment: @YasserKhalil - that's a lot closer. What's with the `& IIf`? There shouldn't be an `&` in your loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me a lot. This solved the problem `For j = IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, LBound(a, 2), UBound(a, 2)) To IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, UBound(a, 2), LBound(a, 2)) Step IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, 1, -1)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does the repeated zigzag direction (left2right-right2left-%) have any practical use or background? - @YasserKhalil

Comment: This was just a question on an Arabic forum from a member. I don't see any practical use in fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works well and I can figure it out with the help of the experts
Thanks a lot for everyone

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    a = Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2))
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For j = IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, LBound(a, 2), UBound(a, 2)) To IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, UBound(a, 2), LBound(a, 2)) Step IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, 1, -1)
            n = n + 1
            If a(i, j) <> Empty Then b(n) = a(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("N2").Resize(n).Value = Application.Transpose(b)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Compacting Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim a: a = Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    Dim ub1 As Long, ub2 As Long: ub1 = UBound(a): ub2 = UBound(a, 2)
    ReDim b(1 To ub1 * ub2)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, md As Long
    For i = 1 To ub1
        md = i Mod 2
        For j = Abs(md - 1) * ub2 + md To md * ub2 + Abs(md - 1) _
                Step 2 * (md - 1) + 1
            n = n + 1
            If a(i, j) <> Empty Then b(n) = a(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("M2").Resize(n).Value = Application.Transpose(b)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got error 'Subscript out of range` at this line `b(n) = a(i, j)` as n = 36 at this point and n should be up to 35 only.

Comment: @YasserKhalil: Sorry, all the time I was thinking that `Step` is `0` for `1 to UBound(UB1)` since it is mostly omitted, but it is `1` by default, of course. So this actually would have been an endless loop where `i` and `j` were `1` all the time, but `UBound` saved the day.